# Force cursor in form field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to force the cursor to stay in one form field. I have an onFocus in the body so when the page first loads the cursor goes to the form field but I need to figure out how to not let it be moved from that field.

I will only have one form field on the whole page. I also need the cursor to go back to that form field even if the browser is minimized and then reopened.

I have been playing with onBlur but it is not working.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha ha! I have it!

The trick is to wait a little bit of time after the blur, and then focus back. Fortunately, we can just set a timeout of 0 seconds, like so:

```
var input = document.getYourInputThatYouWantToFocusOn(),
    focuser = function () {
        input.focus();
    };

focuser();
input.onblur = function () {
    setTimeout(focuser, 0);
};
```

Mwahahahaha!

Answer (score 1):

Forms shouldn't be forcing users to do what they want; instead, they should adapt to users' needs and expectations. You are attempting to force the user to enter only one form field, which goes against web design rules and is a major issue with accessibility.

That said, something of the following should work:

```html
<input type="text" id="field" />
```

JavaScript:

```js
var field = document.getElementById("field");
field.onblur = function() {
    field.focus();
}
```